# How to change endpoint for Android Speech Language Understanding (LUIS) SDK?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I have set up an app on both luis.ai and eu.luis.ai.

I am using this for speech recognition purposes using the SDK provided in this repository: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Android
It has the possibility to use LUIS combined with speech recognition directly, and that is exactly what I need.

It works on luis.ai, because the endpoint is west us. On eu.luis.ai it's not working in the SDK, because it seems like the endpoint is wrong. The appID and subID is wrong for the endpoint.

Is there any way to force the SDK (The one in the repository linked above) to use westeu or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-LUIS-Windows, the LuisClient constructor has an overload that accepts a base URI.  See https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-LUIS-Windows/blob/master/ClientLibrary/LuisClient.cs, specifically:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Construct a new Luis client with a shared <see cref="HttpClient"/> instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="appId">The application ID of the LUIS application</param>
    /// <param name="appKey">The application subscription key of the LUIS application</param>
    /// <param name="baseApiUrl">Root URI for the service endpoint.</param>
    /// <param name="preview">A flag indicating whether to use preview features or not (Dialogue)</param>
    /// top scoring in case of using the dialogue</param>

    public LuisClient(string appId, string appKey, string baseApiUrl, bool preview = false)
```

Update for Android Speech SDK rather than LUIS SDK:

The Android Speech SDK (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Android) has a similar method for specifying the URL.  See the createDataClientWithIntent overload that takes the optional URL parameter at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Android/blob/e27487b57f31afa04f6f3a8badfc566b1885011d/docs/com/microsoft/cognitiveservices/speechrecognition/SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.html:

`createDataClientWithIntent(android.app.Activity activity,
                          java.lang.String language,
                          ISpeechRecognitionServerEvents eventHandlers,
                          java.lang.String primaryKey,
                          java.lang.String secondaryKey,
                          java.lang.String luisAppId,
                          java.lang.String luisSubscriptionId,
                          java.lang.String url)`

Comment: Sorry, this is Android. I guess I only mentioned it in the title, will update to make it more clear.